# Best way to process texts and decode videos while loading the data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataframe which looks like this:
[image]

I'm building a model which takes text and video as input. So, my aim is to load the `Text` and `Media_location` (which contains video files path) from the dataframe, so that it is iterable when I feed `df['Text']` and the video (loaded from path `df['Media_location']`) together.

I couldn't find any implemenations in tensorflow that would do this sort of thing, so drop any suggestions you may have.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe

Comment: there is no implementation of loading video from path and mapping it to text in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `tensorflow-io`, which will run in graph mode. Just run `pip install tensorflow-io` and then try:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Text': ['some text', 'some more text'],
                        'Media_location': ['/content/sample-mp4-file.mp4', '/content/sample-mp4-file.mp4']})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['Text'], df['Media_location']))

def decode_videos(x, y):
  video = tf.io.read_file(y)
  video = tfio.experimental.ffmpeg.decode_video(video)
  return x, video

dataset = dataset.map(decode_videos)

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y.shape)
```

```
tf.Tensor(b'some text', shape=(), dtype=string) (901, 270, 480, 3)
tf.Tensor(b'some more text', shape=(), dtype=string) (901, 270, 480, 3)
```

In this example, each video contains 901 frames.

If you are a `Windows` users, you can try using `cv2` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Text': ['some text', 'some more text'],
                        'Media_location': ['/content/sample-mp4-file.mp4', '/content/sample-mp4-file.mp4']})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['Text'], df['Media_location']))


def get_video_asarray(path):
  frames = []
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path.numpy().decode("utf-8"))
  read = True
  while read:
      read, img = cap.read()
      if read:
        frames.append(img)
  return np.stack(frames, axis=0)


def decode_videos(x, y):
  y = tf.py_function(get_video_asarray, [y], Tout=[tf.float32])
  return x, tf.squeeze(y, axis=0)

dataset = dataset.map(decode_videos)

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y.shape)
```

```
tf.Tensor(b'some text', shape=(), dtype=string) (901, 270, 480, 3)
tf.Tensor(b'some more text', shape=(), dtype=string) (901, 270, 480, 3)
```

Comment: there was a error while I replicated this code. It said: `NotImplementedError: ('could not find ffmpeg after search through ', ['libtensorflow_io_ffmpeg_4.2.so', 'libtensorflow_io_ffmpeg_3.4.so', 'libtensorflow_io_ffmpeg_2.8.so'])` . Let me know if you need the traceback call

Comment: What tensorflow version and OS are you using?

Comment: tf version: 2.7.0 and OS: windows

Comment: Hmm here we read that there is no support for windows: https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/1064

Comment: @PrithvirajKanaujia Kindly check updated answer.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking in the same direction for using opencv, I will check and will let you know

Comment: Seems to work pretty well, if you cannot use a tensorflow-io function.

Comment: yup works well for those who want the video in a tensor form. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence`.

```py
import math
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

class Dataloader(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, df, y_array, batch_size):
        self.df, self.y_array = df, y_array
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.df) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        slices = slice(idx*self.batch_size, (idx+1)*self.batch_size, None)
        return [(tuple(a), b) for a, b in zip(self.df[['Text', 'Media_location']].iloc[slices].values, self.y_array[slices])]
```

example:

```py
import numpy as np

for batch in Dataloader(df, np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10), 3):
    for (text, video), label in batch:
        print((text, video), label)
    print()
```

output:

```
('E DDC', 'Videos\\17.mp4') 0
('CBAD ', 'Videos\\80.mp4') 1
('EBBBBB E', 'Videos\\07.mp4') 1

('ABB B ', 'Videos\\68.mp4') 0
('BCDADDA A', 'Videos\\73.mp4') 1
('CDECECADE', 'Videos\\04.mp4') 1

('EADBDBC', 'Videos\\85.mp4') 1
('ABCCBC AA', 'Videos\\50.mp4') 1
('DEBCA', 'Videos\\32.mp4') 1

('DD CCCB', 'Videos\\24.mp4') 0
```

Comment: the mapping of `df['text']` to `df['Media_location']` is alright, but I need to load the video from the path as well. So how would I load the video from its path?

Comment: i think i can get around with opencv to load the video